# How to cast string parameter to int in a "limit"

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id) vetid, 
                c.clinic_id, 
                c.clinic_name, 
                c.type, 
                c.city, 
                c.state, 
                c.country, 
                c.lat, 
                c.lng, 
                c.zip, 
                ( 3959 * Acos( Cos( Radians(44.977498) ) * Cos( Radians( c.lat ) ) * Cos( Radians( c.lng ) - Radians(-93.406556) ) + Sin( Radians(44.977498) ) * Sin( Radians( c.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM            biah_clinics c 
WHERE           opt_out != '1' 
AND             c.country = 'US' 
HAVING          distance < '10' 
ORDER BY        distance limit cast('20' AS int);
```

Using Drupal's db_query, all parameters passed to the query are passed as STRING. This is giving me an error. That is why in my query, I want to cast that parameter to INT.

So it should end up like this:

```
limit cast('20' AS int);
limit 20;
```

But this is giving me an error in MySQL:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CAST('25' AS
>   INT)' at line 15"

Comment: Why not simply use `LIMIT 20` ? `LIMIT` clause cannot work with expressions/variables etc. It specifically needs a integer literal

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya because Drupal's function is passing the parameters as PDO::STR and I cannot change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using drupal's db_query_range(), due to sql limit doesn't work but with integer literals.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query_range/7.x